# Android compatibility, how to use view attributes that only work on newer versions?

Tags: java, android

I'm sure this is an "easy" question, but I'm totally new to android and java. 
Basically there are certain attributes that have been changed on later versions eg:

```
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

(older)

```
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

(newer)

What happens to older versions if I use the second option? Would they work correctly or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In older versions of android, the `screenSize` attribute will just get ignored. You are fine to use the second `configChanges` in all versions.